# Remove Body Attribute/prefix on a SOAPBodyElement, what should I do?

Tags: java, soap

I want to get a message that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
 xmlns="http://website.com/">
   <S:Header/>
   <S:Body>
      <subscriberCreate>
         <assignedId>Some ID</assignedId>
      </subscriberCreate>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

but gets a message that looks like this(want to get rid of xmlns="" after subscriberCreate):

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
     xmlns="http://website.com/">
    <S:Header/>
        <S:Body>
            <subscriberCreate xmlns="">
                <assignedID>Some ID</assignedID>
            </createSubscriber>
        </S:Body>
    </S:Envelope>
```

Anyone know what to do to fix this? Does the body element inherit the attribute from the envelope because when I changed the order on them the message disapeared!
Thanks!

My java code looks like this:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBodyElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConstants;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
public class CreateSubscriber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try{

            SOAPMessage sm = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL).createMessage();

            SOAPEnvelope env = sm.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
            env.setPrefix("S");
            env.removeNamespaceDeclaration("env");
            sm.getSOAPHeader().setPrefix("S");
            SOAPBody body = sm.getSOAPBody();


            body.setPrefix("S");

            SOAPBodyElement element = body.addBodyElement(env.createName("createSubscriber"));
            env.setAttribute("xmlns","http://psm.proceranetworks.com/soap/3.1/message");
            element.addChildElement("assignedID").addTextNode("Some ID");

            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream("SoapMessage.xml");
            String stdEncode = "<xml version= 1.0 encoding= utf-8>";
            System.out.print(stdEncode);
            sm.writeTo(System.out);


            fOut.write(stdEncode.getBytes());
            sm.writeTo(fOut);

            System.out.println();

            System.out.println("SOAP msg created");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change this line? `SOAPBodyElement element = body.addBodyElement(env.createName("createSubscriber"));`

Comment: Want to get rid of the text ** xmlns="" **! But thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I tried your code and you're missing the quotes and de '?' in your enconding string:

```
String stdEncode = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
```

Comment: Nope, still the same problem. As I commented, want to get rid of the text xmlns = "" after the text **subscriberCreate**

Comment: I've read in the API that the method addChildElement inherets any in-scope namespace. Can I get around this?

Comment: I think the problem is that what you're trying to achieve is against the XML specification :/